# Flutter StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> not passing value into child StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a specific icon to appear based on whether the user has taken the survey or not.

At the moment, I am using `StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>` to listen for a given value in a document, which returns the survey name. I then want to use the survey name in the next `StreamBuilder`, which will look in a given collection (which is made up of the survey name followed by `_entrants` - so, for example, `Survey_entrants`) for a completed survey document, which will have the title of the user's unique id (named `userid`).

The problem I have now is that whilst `surveyName` does return the name of the survey put in Cloud Firestore, and updates it when I change the value (I can see this by the commented-out `return new Text('$surveyName');` command).

However, it does not seem to be passing that value into the next StreamBuilder - regardless of what I put in as the survey name, I get the check icon showing, suggesting `(snapshot1.hasData)` - even when that document does *not* exist.

I know the `surveyName` variable is working, but if I do `snapshot1.toString()` I get the error `Snapshot<DocumentSnapshot>(ConnectionState.active, Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', null)`. This must count has having data, hence showing the survey being taken. How do I correct this?

My code:

```
Positioned(
  right: 30,
  top: 20,
  child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance
    .collection('Controller')
    .document('Current Survey')
    .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else {
        var sn = snapshot.data;
        surveyName = sn["cs"];
//      return new Text('$surveyName');
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('$surveyName' + '_entrants')
          .document(userid)
          .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot1) {
            if (!snapshot1.hasData) {
              return Icon(
                Foundation.burst_new,
                size: 48,
                color: Color(0xff303841),
              );
            } else if (snapshot1.hasData) {
              return Icon(
                Foundation.check,
                size: 48,
                color: Color(0xff303841),
              );
            } else {
              return Icon(
                MaterialIcons.error_outline,
                size: 48,
                color: Color(0xff303841),
              );
            }
          });
      }
    })),
```

Comment: Could you please explain where do you want to put snapshot1.toString() ? I understand that you the StreamBuilder is not passing the data correctly to the child StreamBuilder. Could you please ``print()`` snapshot1 to look properly what is printing snaphot1?

Comment: Hi, I don't want to use `snapshot1.toString()`, I was just using it as a debugging tool to help me figure out what was going on. When I `print(snapshot1)` I get `AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>(ConnectionState.active, Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', null)`